# Reading a binary input stream into a single byte array in Java

Tags: java, inputstream

[The documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) says that one should not use `available()` method to determine the size of an `InputStream`. How can I read the whole content of an `InputStream` into a byte array?

```
InputStream in; //assuming already present
byte[] data = new byte[in.available()];
in.read(data);//now data is filled with the whole content of the InputStream
```

I could read multiple times into a buffer of a fixed size, but then, I will have to combine the data I read into a single byte array, which is a problem for me.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The simplest approach IMO is to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki) and its [`ByteStreams`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) class:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
```

Or for a file:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.toByteArray(file);
```

Alternatively (if you didn't want to use Guava), you could create a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), and repeatedly read into a byte array and write into the `ByteArrayOutputStream` (letting that handle resizing), then call [`ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29).

Note that this approach works whether you can tell the length of your input or not - assuming you have enough memory, of course.

Comment: thank you. Made it work now. I guess I will have to read in chunks and then merge the resulting byte arrays into a single one.

Comment: @Qiang: That's basically what all of the solutions I've presented do - you don't need to do much work yourself for this.

Answer (score 63):

Please keep in mind that the answers here assume that the length of the file is less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`(2147483647).

If you are reading in from a file, you can do something like this:

```
    File file = new File("myFile");
    byte[] fileData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    dis.readFully(fileData);
    dis.close();
```

---

### UPDATE (May 31, 2014):

Java 7 adds some new features in the java.nio.file package that can be used to make this example a few lines shorter. See the [readAllBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes%28java.nio.file.Path%29) method in the [java.nio.file.Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class. Here is a short example:

```
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

// ...
        Path p = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("", "myFile");
        byte [] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(p);
```

Android has support for this starting in [Api level 26](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/nio/file/Files?hl=en) (8.0.0, Oreo).

Comment: unforuntately, I am not reading from a file. I am reading from a ZipEntry. Is there anyway to get the file length similar to here?

Answer (score 10):

You can use Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) for this task:

Refer to [this method](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToByteArray%28java.io.File%29):

```
public static byte[] readFileToByteArray(File file) throws IOException
```

Update:

**Java 7** way:

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename));
```

and if it is a text file and you want to convert it to String (change encoding as needed):

```
StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes)).toString()
```

Answer (score 6):

You can read it by chunks (`byte buffer[] = new byte[2048]`) and write the chunks to a ByteArrayOutputStream. From the ByteArrayOutputStream you can retrieve the contents as a byte[], without needing to determine its size beforehand.

Answer (score 5):

I believe buffer length needs to be specified, as memory is finite and you may run out of it

Example:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(strFileName);
    long length = fileFileName.length();

    if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IOException("File is too large!");
    }

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];

    int offset = 0;
    int numRead = 0;

    while (offset < bytes.length && (numRead = in.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0) {
        offset += numRead;
    }

    if (offset < bytes.length) {
        throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + fileFileName.getName());
    }

    in.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Max value for array index is Integer.MAX_INT - it's around 2Gb (2^31 / 2 147 483 647).
Your input stream can be bigger than 2Gb, so you have to process data in chunks, sorry.

```
        InputStream is;
        final byte[] buffer = new byte[512 * 1024 * 1024]; // 512Mb
        while(true) {
            final int read = is.read(buffer);
            if ( read < 0 ) {
                break;
            }
            // do processing 
        }
```

Comment: I would -1 weren't for the info on max int - you should not write unnecessarily complicated code  - `while(true)` for gosh sake - please edit : `int read; while(read = is.read(buffer) > 0 )`