# Java code to read .txt file and convert into binary representation

Tags: java, encryption, io, binary

Help guys I am a bit stuck on this :( I am doing Simplified DES(SDES) in Java. How can I convert the files into binary representations before encryption? Any help is much appreciated.

I am thinking of reading the text file via FileInputStream, DataInputStream and BufferedReader and put them into a string(but the text file is really long). Then probably use getBytes() to present the bytes in binary form. Sorry I am weak in Java programming and please feel free to give advise. Will be great if someone can come up with a sample source code

Comment: So far what you have tried ?

Comment: check out this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7250229/1904979) about reading binary data.  You can read a text file as binary data same as anything else

Comment: You don't need DataInputStream to read a text file.  You just need BufferedReader and FileReader.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to convert them? Just encrypt them as they come.

Comment: It's a requirement for my assignment :/